# Yii Login routing issue

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I have following problem.

My project in Yii uses standard authentication and RBAC system.
If user is not logged it and visit link like
`https://domain.com/product/update?id=1234`
he will be automatically redirected to homepage
`https://domain.com/site/index`
to process login.

After he logs in he still will be redirected at the right site (`/product/update?id=1234`). The problem is, that external software like MS Excel tries to pre-open the page itself and automatically changes to link to `https://domain.com/site/index`.
So what I need, is that link should always be the same.

That means if user visit `/product/update?id=1234`, then application should stay on `/product/update?id=1234`, but show to login form and after login stay on `/product/update?id=1234`.

I can not understand if it is kind of server routing issue (we are using Nginx) or it could be configuration in Yii or that need some more functionality that Yii doesn't have. Has someone already issued the same problem and can help me with solution? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: wtf is excel doing there? -)) btw, have look up this. navigate over the pages and observe the triggering of login.

Comment: you just have to save the referer on the login page to know where the user comes from

Comment: The main problem that the managers that are using the software together with excel and inserting links in excel can not visit this link, because excel tries to pre-open them and redirect to the login page.

Comment: CROZET, referer is saved and redirects after logging. Thus that works only if I do copy-paste link in browser and then login, but not then I come directly from third-party software. So there is the need, that link should always stay the same, even on the login page.

Comment: Yii 1 or Yii2? Also, have you tried looking through MS's support pages for an Excel solution to this problem?

Comment: It is yii1. We had no success looking through MS support pages.

Comment: You could use Yii's CController classes `beforeRender` method and check if the user is logged in before the view is rendered and render the login form instead of the normal view

Comment: @Brett Gregson, I've tried but had no success. And also I wanted to have this on whole project. So I've tried to overwrite the function in CController, but I always get login page page if user is not logged in. So I assume that redirection happens before.

Comment: @Bfcm let's talk in chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133335/41614484